# How to access next.js rendered HTML via custom server

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want a server side generated page in next.js to be served as a file. So I wanted to grab the rendered content inside a custom server.js file:

```js
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({dev});
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const nextResponse = await app.renderToHTML(req, res, '/', req.query);

    console.log('nextResponse', nextResponse);
    console.log('res.body', res.body);
  });

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

Oddly enough every console.log returns null or undefined.
I thought that `renderToHTML` would just return the rendered HTML string. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: apprently, `renderToHtml()` doesn't return HTML SSR code, and sends to response socket automatically https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/14737. Try overwritting the middleware `response.send` method as shown here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares with a reference to your own `nextResponse` to access after the call

Answer (score 1):

This one is a bit tricky but achievable.

The idea is to override `res.end` function in order to catch rendered HTML there. The tricky part is that Next.js gzips and streams response using the [compression](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression) library that's overriding `res.end` somewhere in the middle of the `handle` function.

The compression library is initialized using the `handleCompression` function of the Next.js's Server object (which is accessible using the `app.getServer()`), so that function needs to get overridden too.

So it should be looking something like this:

```
const { parse } = require('url');
const next = require('next');
const express = require('express');
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare()
.then(() => {
    const server = express();

    server.get('*', async (req, res) => {
        const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);

        const nextServer = await app.getServer();
        const _handleCompression = nodeServer.handleCompression.bind(nodeServer);

        nextServer.handleCompression = (req, res) => {
            _handleCompression(req, res);

            const _resEnd = res.end.bind(res)
            res.end = function (payload) {
                console.log('Rendered HTML: ', payload);

                return _resEnd(payload);
            }
        }

        return handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
    });

    server.listen(port, err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:' + port);
    });
});
```

After you get rendered HTML you don't have to use the saved `_resEnd` function. Feel free to manipulate, serve as a file, or whatever you want with it.

Comment: nodeServer is undefined... Where'd you get it from?

Comment: May be nodeServer  need renamed to nextServer
but code is not worked

Comment: Previously, in older versions of NextJS (11.0.1 for example), in res.end(payload) server gave the payload and it was possible to use them for memjs in server.js. Since version 12 res.end() is called without payload and there is no way to get the data to put it into cache.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted Nikola Knežević solution for NextJS 13.2.3, and it does the job :

```js
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')
const express = require('express')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = 'localhost'
const port = 3000
// when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port, dir: '<absolute root path to your project>' })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express()

    server.get('*', async (req, res) => {
        const nextServer = await app.getServer()
        const _handleCompression = nextServer.handleCompression.bind(nextServer)

        nextServer.handleCompression = (req, res) => {
            _handleCompression(req, res)
            const _resEnd = res._res.end.bind(res._res)

            res._res.end = function (payload) {
                // payload contains the html content
                return _resEnd(payload)
            }
        }

        return handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
    })

    server.listen(port, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err
        }
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
})
```